# In the Delayed "Choice" Quantum Eraser experiment, what is observed between detection of the signal photon and the idler photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-eraser

[image]

It is mentioned in the study that:

> In the experiment the optical delay (LA,B 2 L0) is chosen to be  2.3 m, where L0 is the optical distance between the output surface of BBO and detector D0, and LA
>   (LB) is the optical distance between the output surface of
>   the BBO and the beam splitter BSA (BSB). This means
>   that any information (which-path or both-path) one can infer from photon 2 must be at least 7.7 ns later than the
>   registration of photon 1. Compared to the 1 ns response
>   time of the detectors, a 2.3 m delay is thus sufficient for
>   the “delayed erasure.” Although there is an arbitrariness in
>   the time when a photon is detected, it is safe to say that
>   the choice of photon 2 is delayed with respect to the detection of photon 1 at D0 since the entangled photon pair
>   is created simultaneously.

This means that once the signal photon reaches detector 0, there is a gap until the idler photon reaches either one of Detector 1, 2, 3 or 4; 7.7 ns according to the study. My question is, what exactly is observed in detector 0 between this 7.7 ns gap? The study claims that the gap is noticeable by the electronics

> Compared to the 1 ns response
>   time of the detectors, a 2.3 m delay is thus sufficient for
>   the “delayed erasure.”

, so there must be some kind of pattern, or not detected. This wasn't clear to me in the study, could you please explain if my understanding is wrong, or what happens? Since the "which-way" information has not been confirmed yet, you would expect to see an interference pattern. However, the results show a lack of interference pattern when the idler photon is detected in D4 or D3. Do the results change after the detection of the idler photon?

This is one of those things that is explored in all the youtube videos, but never really explained properly. Some say its "changing the results back in time", or that "the photon is able to predict whether it will be detected or not". What's up here?

Unfortunately I haven't had the chance to properly study Schrodinger's equation yet, as a high school student, so mathematical models may not help me much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the "study" you are referring to here? Can you add a link/reference? I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. The "gap" is between the moment you see a signal on $D_0$ and the moment you see the signal on $D_1$. By definition, you don't observe anything in the between these two times .You have to imagine that these are detectors that either "click" or don't "click". So in the gap you simply don't observe anything (or if you prefer, you observe "no clicks")